# How to find an internal identifier for an Odoo database?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

In Python, I want to pass a unique identifier for an Odoo database to a third-party application so that I can identify which DB the request has come from.

Where can I find a unique identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Odoo standard context variable.

For example:

```
self.env.cr.dbname
```

or

```
self._cr.dbname
```

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could point me to the documentation or source code for "env".

Comment: Sure. Here you can read more about environment. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#environment

Comment: And the "cursor" object? I'm trying to understand where to find the answer you provided for myself.

Answer (score 0):

The Unique ID of your database can be found like this:

```
env['ir.config_parameter'].search([('key','=','database.uuid')])[0].value
```

Output:
'7571db5a-4f28-442e-b701-c391a7b13abe'

Or with the following SQL query: select value from ir_config_parameter where key = 'database.uuid'

Or in the UI : in App Settings :
Switch to debug mode by adding "?debug=1" in your url, reload the page: Then go to the last item in the top menu bar: **Technical**
in the dropdown menu > **System settings** ... And in the displayed table, look for **database.uuid**